# While trying to open a installed library, getting error "compilation failed for package"

Tags: r

After I installed the package `MASS` I tried to open it and I am getting errors "'stdlib.h' file not found," "compilation failed for package 'MASS'," and "there is no package called 'MASS'." Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You didn't install `MASS` - the first error tells you that compilation from source failed as a header library could not be found. As you are on a Mac, there should be no need to install from source - answer "no" when asked.

Comment: It looks like you're using Anaconda on a Mac. Please retry installing via Anaconda: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/

Comment: If you install R in the standard way, you won't need to build MASS.  It will just work.  Download it from https://cloud.r-project.org.